# Clicking Button in Gridview Disables other Buttons

Tags: c#, silverlight, xaml, button, datagrid

I'm creating a Windows Gadget currently, it contains a Gridview in my Flyout. When the user clicks a button in the Flyout I want it to disable the rest of the buttons in the row, my `xaml` code is below:

```
<sdk:DataGrid AutoGenerateColumns="False" Height="245" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="12,43,0,0" Name="dataIssue" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="512">
    <sdk:DataGrid.Columns>
        <sdk:DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Path=ID}" Header="ID"/>
        <sdk:DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Path=subject}" Header="Subject"/>
        <sdk:DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Path=project_ID}" Header="Project ID"/>
        <sdk:DataGridTemplateColumn Width="80" Header="Timer">
            <sdk:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Button Content="Start" Click="Timer_Click"></Button>
                </DataTemplate>
            </sdk:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        </sdk:DataGridTemplateColumn>
    </sdk:DataGrid.Columns>
</sdk:DataGrid>
```

Any help on this would be appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only thing I can think of is that you have a `SelectedID` on the viewmodel and bind the `IsEnabled` property of the button to the list through a converter. This would check if the ID  of the element was the selected ID. If not then return false to disable the button.

You'd need to check that if there's nothing selected and return `true` to enable all the buttons.

Comment: Chris, would you be able to expand on this a bit please? Give a code example if possible?
    `if (this.IsEnabled == true)`
    ` {`
      ` IsTimer = false;`
    `}`

    `if (IsTimer == false)`
    `this.IsEnabled = false;`

The above code is in my Timer_Click method, is this correct?

Comment: No worries, decided to go a different route with this lol thanks for the help though!